# Symfony2, Doctrine2, Entity insert then update at once

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

Simple thing, but doesn't work. We have at the bottom part of script

```
    $oMan = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    // add entry of calling
    $oLastCall = new CronLastCall();
    $oLastCall->setType('key');

    $oMan->persist($oLastCall);
    $oMan->flush();
```

we insert to db once we create it, then do some stuff that can take a few minutes. Then call this one.

```
    $oLastCall->setDateEnd(new \DateTime('now'));
    $oMan->flush();
```

after this one - exist from method\action. So regarding logic (and doctrine2 manual I read) entity that were created already become 'managed' (we persist it) and we can simply update it. (I call flush (at the end) to update this entity, but it not updating.)

Where is trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with the code you've shown. But if the `$oLastCall` object becomes detached between the first and second code blocks, you have to re-attach (merge) it to the manager so that it detects the changes for the second flush.

Merging can be done in this way:

```
$oLastCallMerged = $oMan->merge($oLastCall);
$oLastCallMerged->setDateEnd(new \DateTime('now'));
$oMan->flush();
```

You can also check the state (MANAGED/NEW/DETACHED/REMOVED) of an object using this code:

```
$oMan->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityState($oLastCall);
```

If that doesn't help (i.e. detachment of the object isn't your problem), you need to give more info about the context this code runs in and any errors you get. Is this code part of a [Console Command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) or a regular web-app Controller? Do you get any output or errors when running it in 'dev' environment? (Check `.../app/logs/dev.log`.) Does the `$oLastCall` object stay in memory while waiting for the stuff that takes some minutes, or do you reload it from somewhere?

Btw, objects doesn't magically get detached by themselves. They'll only be detached if you load them from a different source than the entity manager (for example storing them in the session between requests) OR if you explicitly detach them by calling `$oMan->detach($entity)` or `$oMan->clear()`.

#### Edit

You can also check if Doctrine detects the change by echoing out the changeset using `$oMan->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($oLastCall)` before and after the change, e.g:

```
error_log(json_encode($oMan->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($oLastCall)));
$oLastCall->setDateEnd(new \DateTime('now'));
error_log(json_encode($oMan->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($oLastCall)));
```

Comment: It's Console Command method. I'm calling from one entity manager. It's running on one method call. Mb there is another way out, if we know that entity after flush is detached can we attach it manually (not to do select query, simply attach entity) ?

Comment: @user1954544 It shouldn't be detached by the flush itself, but it can still become detached during the wait if other parts of your application clear/detach it from the same manager instance. You should double-check this by using the `getEntityState` method, as shown above. Also, try checking the changeset before and after the change (see the edit, above). If the changeset doesn't change, perhaps it's a mapping problem?

Comment: I played with it and found solution. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

After flushing the manager all objects will be removed internally from the manager. So if you want to update the object later you need to call persist again before flushing.

Comment: yeah, it's something like this, but can I do this one without 'second' selection for updating?

Comment: Well another way would be to pass the object you want to update directly to the flush method like: $oMan->flush($oLastCall);